# Find files and add a line

Tags: bash, sed, batch-processing

I am doing `bash` script and I need to add a line to all files of the type `.info` in a directory and subdirectories of that directory.

The text I want to add is `version = $version`  on new line in the end of the file.

All I have for now is:

```
find ./ -name '*.info'
```

Which lists the files, but do nothing... I am pretty new in `bash` scripting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this line

```
find /DIR -name "*.info"|xargs sed -i '$a\version = $version'
```

Comment: If I changed it to: `find  -name "*.info"|xargs sed -i '$a \version='$version''` it worked like a charm, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add `-exec` option, like this

```
find . -name '*.info' -exec bash -c 'echo "version = \$version" > {}' ';'
```

Comment: I think I am doing something wrong, in both of the examples the variable is not pinted as an variable, but as an string `$variable` becomes `$variable` instead of `7.x-1.x` that I want....

It looke like this:

    git clone --recursive http://git.drupal.org/project/$project.git $target
    cd $target
    git checkout -q $version
    find  -name "*.info"|xargs sed -i '$a \version=$version'

Comment: @Anton I think you should update your command as `find . -name '*.info' -exec bash -c 'echo "version = \$version" >> {}' ';'`
`>>` to redirect. `>` to overwrite.